# Pandas Ordering columns in order

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, sorting

I'm trying to order different columns by alphabetical order.
I used the following code :

```
def CodeRegex (df):
    dfRegex = df.filter(regex="x[1-9][0-9]?|p")
    dfRegex = dfRegex.reindex_axis(sorted(dfRegex.columns), axis=1)
    return dfRegex
```

My problem is that my headers looks like "x1", "x2, ..., "x10, "x11", ..., "x20", "x21" ...

When I order it, the result is :
"x1", "x10", "x11", ..., "x2", "x20", "x21", ...

Do you know what I can do to change the order ?
I can't put "x01", "x02".

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem your columns are strings, so there are lexicographically sorted.

Use `sorted` by `lambda` function with convert columns values to `integer`s. `x[1:]` is for remove `x` from each value, also there should be value `p`, so is possible choose if need first or last value of sorted columns:

```
dfRegex = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x1', 'x10', 'x2', 'x20', 'x3','p'])

dfRegex = dfRegex.reindex(columns=sorted(dfRegex.columns, key=lambda x: int(x[1:]) if x!='p' else 0))
print (dfRegex)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [p, x1, x2, x3, x10, x20]
Index: []

dfRegex = dfRegex.reindex(columns=sorted(dfRegex.columns, key=lambda x: int(x[1:]) if x!='p' else 100))
print (dfRegex)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [x1, x2, x3, x10, x20, p]
Index: []
```

Comment: You could also comment why the OP is seeing the current behavior, namely because those `x123` column names are sorting as text, and not numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

The reason your sorting fails is because your column names are strings, so they are sorting *as strings*. So, for example, `'x20'` will be sorted *before* `'x3'`.

You can sort numerically by extracting the integer component. Then index with [`pd.Dataframe.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) via `np.argsort`:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x1', 'x10', 'x2', 'x20', 'x3'])

args = np.argsort(df.columns.str[1:].astype(int))
df = df.iloc[:, args]

print(df.columns)

Index(['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x10', 'x20'], dtype='object')
```

[`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) returns the indices of the original `pd.Index` object which would sort the array:

```
print(args)

array([0, 2, 4, 1, 3], dtype=int64)
```